# Maximum Accumulated Balance after Purchasing Machines

Tags: dynamic-programming, sorting, greedy-algorithms

A company is able to earn `x` dollars per day without any machines. However, there are `n` machines available for purchase. The `i`-th (`0<=i<n`) machine costs `v[i]` and can bring an extra profit of `m[i]` per day to the company. Each machine can be purchased only once, but the company can buy multiple machines on the same day. If the company has `0` dollars on the first day, what is the maximum balance of the company at the end of the `k`-th day?

I have no idea how to solve this problem at the moment, so I'm tagging with some possible algorithms.

Comment: What are the constraints (i.e. bounds on $n$ and everything else)?

Comment: Because this is more like an algorithmic study, let's just assume all the values are within the range of 32-bit integers.